# Possible to combine code coverage results (VC++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-coverage

I am using VC++ 2005 and 2008 on a project. Now I want to see if the unit test cases cover all the code, and a found a problem. We use Boost.Test for unit testing, and each file is designed to test a particular function or method. Each file is compiled into a separate executable.

I am able to view the results per executable in Visual Studio. What I am really interested in is to view the overall code coverage by all the tests combined. Is there a way to combine the code coverage results?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Visual Studio's test coverage tools.

Our [SD C++ Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CppTestCoverage.html) will combine test coverage vectors from a single instrumented set of source code, no matter how many times you compile/link it (as long as you don't change the source of the code being tested).  This tool can be obtained for the Visual Studio dialect(s) of C++.  SD's test coverage tools for other languages have this same property.

Answer (score 0):

[C++ Coverage Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-coverage.php) can combine results from different code coverage sessions. You can combine sessions interactively using the GUI or from the command line (so you can automate things).

Alternatively you could set up the automatic merging to a central session and get every code coverage session automatically merged into the central session.